# XSLT - Pushing an element to the bottom of the page

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo

I would like to know what are the methods of pushing a block element at the bottom of the page. I am aware of the `<fo:region-after>` object, but I don't know how to use this for a single page, because the element I want to push to the bottom of the page will happen only on one page and only if a condition is met.

The block I want to push is this:

```
<fo:block font-size="0" margin-top="10mm" margin-bottom="10mm" margin-left="-10mm">
    <fo:external-graphic width="190mm" content-width="scale-to-fit">
        <xsl:attribute name="src">            
            url('./test.jpg')
        </xsl:attribute>
    </fo:external-graphic>
</fo:block>
```

The page configuration looks like this:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <fo:root xsl:use-attribute-sets="body" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
        <fo:layout-master-set>
            <fo:simple-page-master master-name="first"
                page-height="297mm"
                page-width="210mm"
                margin-top="0mm"
                margin-bottom="0mm"
                margin-left="0mm"
                margin-right="0mm">
                <fo:region-body margin-bottom="0" margin-top="0mm" />
                <fo:region-before region-name="header-first" extent="0mm" />
                <fo:region-after region-name="footer-first" extent="20mm" />
            </fo:simple-page-master>
            <fo:simple-page-master master-name="rest"
                page-height="297mm"
                page-width="210mm"
                margin-top="20mm"
                margin-bottom="20mm"
                margin-left="20mm"
                margin-right="20mm">
                <fo:region-body margin-bottom="0" margin-top="0" />
                <fo:region-before region-name="header-rest" extent="0" />
                <fo:region-after region-name="footer-rest" extent="0mm" />
            </fo:simple-page-master>
            <fo:page-sequence-master master-name="document">
                <fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives>
                    <fo:conditional-page-master-reference
                        page-position="first"
                        master-reference="first" />
                    <fo:conditional-page-master-reference
                        page-position="rest"
                        master-reference="rest" />
                </fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives>
            </fo:page-sequence-master>
        </fo:layout-master-set>
        <fo:page-sequence id="sequenceID" master-reference="document">
            <fo:static-content flow-name="header-first">
                <fo:block></fo:block>
            </fo:static-content>
            <fo:static-content flow-name="header-rest">
                <xsl:call-template name="header">
                    <xsl:with-param name="attribute-set"></xsl:with-param>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </fo:static-content>
            <fo:static-content flow-name="footer-first">
                <xsl:call-template name="footer-first" />
            </fo:static-content>
            <fo:static-content flow-name="footer-rest">
                <xsl:call-template name="footer-rest" />
            </fo:static-content>
            <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">                
                <xsl:apply-templates select="//PRINTED_SECTIONS" />
            </fo:flow>
        </fo:page-sequence>
    </fo:root>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 2):

1. If you are using AH Formatter, you can float the graphic to the bottom of the `fo:region-body` by using `fo:float` with `axf:float-y="bottom"`.  See https://www.antennahouse.com/product/ahf64/ahf-float.html and "Arranging floats in any positions in a page (axf:float-reference=”page”)" from https://www.antennahouse.com/antenna1/comprehensive-xsl-fo-tutorials-and-samples-collection/
2. You can put the graphic in an `fo:footnote`.  You might need to also generate an empty `fo:static-content` with `flow-name="xsl-footnote-separator"` to override the formatter's default, if the default is to output a horizontal line or similar as the footnote separator.  See https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#fo_page-sequence and other references to 'xsl-footnote-separator'.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Tony. I think the second option is more suitable, but can you help me with an example with the block that I want to push? I don't know/understand how can I add that block only for a specific page.

Comment: What determines which page is the specific page?  I thought that you meant the page where the graphic occurred in the flow.  If it has to appear on, say, page 3 only, then you're back to looking at the `fo:page-sequence-master` and selecting the correct page master for that page.

Comment: You can look at the multiple footnote example PDF and XSL-FO files at https://www.antennahouse.com/antenna1/comprehensive-xsl-fo-tutorials-and-samples-collection/, plus there's other footnote questions here on StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=xsl-fo+fo%3Afootnote